# Probability of a Union of Events

Tags: probability, induction

Using induction, prove the following statement:

Let $A_n$ represent different events. Let $P(A_n)$ represent the probability of the event occurring.

$P[A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n] \leq P(A_1) + P(A_2) + ... + P(A_n)$.

Comment: Just realized that. Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle